# How to resolve npm err: while resolving ... found...?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, chakra-ui

My project uses `Chakra-UI` and `React`. When trying to run `npm install`, I got this npm error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @choc-ui/chakra-autocomplete@5.1.2
npm ERR! Found: @chakra-ui/react@1.8.8
npm ERR! node_modules/@chakra-ui/react
npm ERR!   @chakra-ui/react@"latest" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @chakra-ui/react@"^2.2.8" from @choc-ui/chakra-autocomplete@5.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@choc-ui/chakra-autocomplete
npm ERR!   @choc-ui/chakra-autocomplete@"^5.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@">=18" from @chakra-ui/react@2.3.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@chakra-ui/react
npm ERR!     peer @chakra-ui/react@"^2.2.8" from @choc-ui/chakra-autocomplete@5.1.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@choc-ui/chakra-autocomplete
npm ERR!       @choc-ui/chakra-autocomplete@"^5.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I don't understand this error, I tried deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, ran `npm install` again, but same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overriding peer dependency error on npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72631164/overriding-peer-dependency-error-on-npm-install)

Answer (score -1):

run again npm install --legacy-peer-deps that will solve your issue